# How can I attach a disk to existing ZFS zpool mirror with Ubuntu and ZEVO?

Tags: mac, partition, unix, zfs, macos

Is it possible to attach a third hdd to a already created mirror consisting of two hdds with ZEVO?

### Ubuntu

I run an Ubuntu Virtual Machine with native ZFS support. When I attach the third hdd it works flawlessly.

### OS X Lion

When I import the pool to Lion, ZEVO argues that one pool is missing even though it is there and gets resilvered at the moment.

---

On Ubuntu:

```
$ zpool status Toshiba_ZFS

pool: Toshiba_ZFS
state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
scan: resilver in progress since Sun Aug 19 15:03:18 2012
12.1G scanned out of 598G at 14.4M/s, 11h33m to go
929M resilvered, 2.02% done

config:

NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
Toshiba_ZFS  ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdb5    ONLINE       0     0     5  (resilvering)
```

On Mac OS X (Lion):

```
$ zpool status Toshiba_ZFS

pool: Toshiba_ZFS
state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
scan: resilver in progress since Sun Aug 19 15:03:18 2012
1,52Gi scanned out of 598Gi at 24,0Mi/s, 7h4m to go
242Mi resilvered, 0,25% done
config:

NAME                                           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
Toshiba_ZFS                                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
  mirror-0                                     DEGRADED     0     0     0
    GPTE_1C3475D8-AB6F-3547-AE5D-571C2389DCC7  ONLINE       0     0     0  at disk3s1
    GPTE_11059782-DA42-654B-8577-431C1B80814C  ONLINE       0     0     0  at disk5s1
    16494388674814556229                       UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/sdb5
```

For some reason ZEVO stores the pools in /dev/dsk/ but since my third hdd isnt a pool yet and will be attached to existing zfs mirror pool it wont get recognised

```
$diskutil info disk2s5

Device Identifier:        disk2s5
Device Node:              /dev/disk2s5
Part of Whole:            disk2
Device / Media Name:      tank

Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

File System:              None

Partition Type:           FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
OS Can Be Installed:      No
Media Type:               Generic
Protocol:                 USB
SMART Status:             Not Supported

Total Size:               751.6 GB (751591690240 Bytes) (exactly 1467952520 512-Byte-Blocks)
Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

Read-Only Media:          No
Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
Ejectable:                Yes

Whole:                    No
Internal:                 No[/code]

$ zpool attach Toshiba_ZFS disk3s1 disk2s5
cannot open 'disk2s5': no such device in /dev/dsk
must be a full path or shorthand device name
```

How can I attach another disk with ZEVO?

**EDIT**: Here is some log information from the Console application:

```
20.08.12 09:52:01,000 kernel: ZFSLabelScheme:start: 0xffffff801160e700 created proxy         disk for pool 'Toshiba_ZFS'
20.08.12 09:52:01,000 kernel: ZFSLabelScheme:start: 'Toshiba_ZFS' critical mass with 1     vdev(s) (skip import)
20.08.12 09:52:01,000 kernel: ZFSLabelScheme:probe: label 'Toshiba_ZFS', vdev     8248481474682216015
20.08.12 09:52:01,000 kernel: zfsx_vdm_open: couldn't find vdevMedia for 'sde5'
20.08.12 09:52:01,000 kernel: ldi_open_by_name: Toshiba_ZFS /dev/sde5 error 2, flag 3
20.08.12 09:52:01,000 kernel: zfsx_vdm_open: 'Toshiba_ZFS' disk3s1
20.08.12 09:52:01,000 kernel: zfsx_vdm_open: 'Toshiba_ZFS' disk5s1
20.08.12 09:52:02,000 kernel: zfsx_vdm_open: couldn't find vdevMedia for 'sde5'
20.08.12 09:52:02,000 kernel: ldi_open_by_name: Toshiba_ZFS /dev/sde5 error 2, flag 3
20.08.12 09:52:02,000 kernel: zfsx_mount: '/Volumes/Toshiba_ZFS'
20.08.12 09:52:07,235 com.tenscomplement.zfs.delegate: taking GPTE_11059782-DA42-654B-    8577-431C1B80814C online in pool 'Toshiba_ZFS'
20.08.12 09:52:17,239 com.tenscomplement.zfs.delegate: post mount fsgetpath: err 2, using "/.vol/234881038/2" instead
20.08.12 09:52:17,239 com.tenscomplement.zfs.delegate: post mount processing "/.vol/234881038/2"
```

And the partition table from parted:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Model: External RAID (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      20.5kB  210MB   210MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot
 2      210MB   58.6GB  58.3GB               Macintosh HD
 3      58.7GB  59.3GB  650MB   hfs+         Recovery HD
 4      59.3GB  248GB   189GB   hfs+         Backups
 5      248GB   1000GB  752GB   zfs          Apple_HFS_Untitled_4
```

Comment: Although bought by GreenBytes, Zevo still officially support the product - https://zevo.zendesk.com/home. I'd go there for help, as it's a pretty closed off product.

Comment: Or, you can wait for the Community Edition from GreenBytes, or switch to MacZFS (maczfs.org)

Comment: Already wrote an email to the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. You will have to replicate the current zpool device's partition table to the device you want to attach and then randomize the unique GUIDs of the partitions (should be two). Then you add the device to the zpool mirror and format the unallocated disk space to HFS+ or whatever you like. This all happens inside Linux with [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/gdisk.html) and [parted](http://linux.die.net/man/8/parted) but it will be recognized properly by Mac OS X Zevos ZFS port.

```
$ zpool status Toshiba_ZFS
NAME                                           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
Toshiba_ZFS                                    ONLINE      0     0     0
  mirror-0                                     ONLINE      0     0     0
    GPTE_1C3475D8-AB6F-3547-AE5D-571C2389DCC7  ONLINE      0     0     0  at disk4s1
    GPTE_11059782-DA42-654B-8577-431C1B80814C  ONLINE      0     0     0  at disk3s1
    GPTE_79E12ED8-31EE-384C-B115-2759039256C0  ONLINE      0     0     0  at disk2s1

$ diskutil list 
/dev/disk2
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
1:                        ZFS                         750.1 GB   disk2s1
2: 6A945A3B-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631               8.4 MB     disk2s2
3:          Apple_CoreStorage                         60.5 GB    disk2s3
4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s4
5:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk2s5
6:                  Apple_HFS Backups                 188.4 GB   disk2s6

$ gdisk /dev/disk2
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.2

Partition table scan:
MBR: protective
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/disk2: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): B51307F7-D090-E64A-ADDF-800BFE2EA9AB
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 32-sector boundaries
Total free space is 526309 sectors (257.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
1            2048      1465131007   698.6 GiB   BF01  zfs
2      1465131008      1465147391   8.0 MiB     BF07  
3      1465147392      1583354079   56.4 GiB    AF05  Macintosh_HD
4      1583616224      1584885759   619.9 MiB   AB00  Recovery HD
5      1584885760      1585295359   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
6      1585295360      1953262983   175.5 GiB   AF00
```

Answer (score 0):

> … For some reason zevo stores the pools in /dev/dsk/

In the new ZEVO knowledge base (2012-09-14), [Disk device names](http://zevo.getgreenbytes.com/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=Site.DiskDeviceNames) provides the explanation.

A comparable explanation was published when Ten's Complement sold ZEVO.

> How can I attach a disk to existing zfs zpool mirror with Zevo?
>
> … Ubuntu … When I attach the third hdd it works flawlessly but when I import the pool to Lion …

In the knowledge base, [Creating ZFS pools](http://zevo.getgreenbytes.com/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=Site.CreatingZFSPools) offers three examples that relate to mirrors.

From the ZEVO and OS X perspectives, it's almost certainly better to **begin ZFS-related routines with ZEVO** than with Ubuntu. [Quoting](http://zevo.getgreenbytes.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=178#p178) from the QuickStart Guide for ZEVO Community Edition 1.1:

> > … ZEVO uses the standard ZFS on-disk format (v28) and is therefore binary compatible with ZFS on other platforms. However, direct interchange with other platforms is not supported in this version. ….

A comparable note was published when Ten's Complement sold ZEVO.

## Starting points

http://zevo.getgreenbytes.com links to the knowledge base, support forum and more.